# Form 'Submit', Customer Notification (success or failed)

Tags: magento-1.9, contact-form

I created a really simple custom module with form. Everything works fine with the form. It sends the information to the provided email. However, when the customer fills in the form and clicks on "`submit`" button, it clears the form out but sends the email successfully.

Here is my `.phtml` file for it:

```
            <div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?></div>
            <div class="page-title">
                <h1><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Wholesale Contact') ?></h1>
            </div>

            <form id="contactForm" name="simple_contact_form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('wholesale-simplecontact/') ?>index/sendemail" method="post">

                          <div class="fieldset">
                            <fieldset class="group-select">
                                <h2 class="legend"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Information') ?></h2>
                                <ul>
                                <li class="fields">
                                        <div class="field">
                                            <label for="name">Name <span class="required"><em>*</em></span></label><br />
                         
                                            <input name="name" id="name" title="Name" value="" class="required-entry input-text" type="text" />
                                        </div>
                         
                                        <div class="input-box">
                                            <label for="email">Email <span class="required"><em>*</em></span></label><br />
                                            <input name="email" id="email" title="Email" value="" class="required-entry input-text validate-email" type="text" />
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        <div class="input-box">
                                            <label for="business_name">Business Name <span class="required"><em>*</em></span></label><br />
                                            <input name="business_name" id="business_name" title="Business Name" value="" class="required-entry input-text" type="text" />
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        <div class="input-box">
                                            <label for="business_address">Business Address <span class="required"><em>*</em></span></label><br />
                                            <input name="business_address" id="business_address" title="Business Address" value="" class="required-entry input-text" type="text" />
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        <div class="input-box">
                                            <label for="telephone_number">Telephone Number <span class="required"><em>*</em></span></label><br />
                                            <input name="telephone_number" id="telephone_number" title="Telephone Number" value="" class="required-entry input-text" type="text" />
                                        </div>
                         
                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                         
                                        <div class="input-box">
                                            <label for="comment">Comment</label><br />
                         
                                            <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="Comment" class="required-entry input-text" style="height:100px;" cols="50" rows="3"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                </li>
                                        
                                </ul>
                            </fieldset>
                            </div>
                
                
                <div class="button-set">
                    <p class="required">* Required Fields</p>
                    <button style="float: right; margin-bottom: 10px;" class="button" type="submit"><span>Submit <br></span></button>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </form>
```

And here is my controller for it:

```
        <?php

        class Wholesale_SimpleContact_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
        {
            public function indexAction()
            {
                //Get current layout state
                $this->loadLayout();   

               $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                    'Mage_Core_Block_Template',
                    'wholesale.simple_contact',
                    array(
                        'template' => 'wholesale/simple_contact.phtml'
                    )
                );

               $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
                //$this->getLayout()->getBlock('right')->insert($block, 'catalog.compare.sidebar', true);

               $this->_initLayoutMessages('core/session');

               $this->renderLayout();
            }
             
                    public function sendemailAction() {
                        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
                        $name = $this->getRequest()->getParam('name');
                        $email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');
                        $businessName = $this->getRequest()->getParam('business_name');
                        $businessAddress = $this->getRequest()->getParam('business_address');
                        $telephoneNumber = $this->getRequest()->getParam('telephone_number');
                        $comment = $this->getRequest()->getParam('comment');
                        $body1 = "Name: " .$name ."\r\n";
                        $body2 = "Busines Name: " .$businessName ."\r\n";
                        $body3 = "Address: " .$businessAddress ."\r\n";
                        $body4 = "Telephone: " .$telephoneNumber ."\r\n";
                        $body5 = "Additional Comments: " .$comment ."\r\n";
                        $body = $body1.' '.$body2.' '.$body3.' '.$body4.' '.$body5 ;

                        $mail = new Zend_Mail();
                        $mail->setBodyText($body);
                        $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
                        $mail->addTo('greg@domain.co.uk', 'Some Recipient');
                        $mail->setSubject('Test Wholesale_SimpleContact Module');
                        try {
                            $mail->send();
                        }     
                        catch(Exception $ex) {
                            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send email. Sample of a custom notification error from Wholesale_SimpleContact.');
                        }
                        //Redirect back to index action of (this) wholesale-simplecontact controller
                        $this->_redirect('wholesale-simplecontact/');
                    }
        }

        ?>
```

How can I display a success message to a customer, notifying him that the email has been successfully sent or it failed?

Comment: $this->_redirect('wholesale-simplecontact/?success=true'); send parameter and check that parameter in template file and if that is set then display email sent.

Comment: how can I check the parameter?

Comment: redirect like $this->_redirect('wholesale-simplecontact/?success=1'); 
and in template check like: if($this->getRequest()->getParam('success'))
{
// success message display code.
}

Comment: I got:                      <?php 
    if($this->getRequest()->getParam('success')); 
    {
     echo "success";
    } 
    ?>   But it displays the "success" message all the time regardless the url. Sorry I'm asking easy to solve questions, I'm still a newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have only added this:

```
                        try {
                            $mail->send();
                            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.');
                        }
```

And success message is now being displayed.